# Is it normal if I got a lot of timeout when my wifi underload?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I often got timeout when I ping google this usually happen when my family member opening youtube or downloading something. It is very cheap wireless router I was wondering If I buy new and more expensive router will it fix this? or I should upgrade my ISP package to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more expensive router might or might not fix this depending on where the bottleneck is and if the new router will provide greater throughout.

If the bottleneck is the Internet connection, then changing the router won't help and you need a faster connection. This is the more likely scenario.. That said, it's very possible that the bottleneck is the amount of wifi spectrum available (assuming you are both connecting to WIFI).

To see where the bottleneck is coming in, get WinMTR or similar and do a trace+ping to see where the packet loss is creeping on. If it's on the first hop, replacing the WIFI device with one which provides faster connectivity will help. If it's the second or later hop, then a better Internet connection is warranted (but you might be able to use a feature rich router to share the connection more fairly and reduce your problems through bandwidth limiting or QoS)